# If humans found unlimited energy, would there be more peace or less

Tags: science-based, energy, peace

Fusion reactors would effectively allow us to harvest infinite energy at little cost.  It seems we may be getting close to achieving this - https://www.engadget.com/2018/03/09/mit-embarks-ambitious-plan-build-nuclear-fusion-2033/.

Would it be expected that this would move us towards being a more peaceful planet because:

- Now we don't need to expend the resources and suffer the collateral damage associated with current energy extraction techniques
- No protests over such energy extractions
- No imbalance of power - such as the Middle East where some nations have all the oil wealth and others have none
- Develop (in time) anything we need without further draining other resources - for example, 3D-printing girders for construction using some compound we develop

  - Easily develop and manufacture synthetic proteins or other substitutes that will obviate the need for destructive mass agriculture
- We could likely develop the technology to perform interstellar travel more cheaply and reliably
- We could now produce much less pollution from increased manufacturing
- ...more (what?)

Or lead us away from peace, for reasons such as:

- the loss of jobs in industries such as mining and agriculture
- We become "owned" by the mega-energy corporation(s)
- ...more (what?)

I have more arguments to suggest that such a change will lead to world peace.  Is there something I'm missing that suggests that the world will become less peaceful?

Does there exist any precedents that may suggest how this will turn out (should unlimited energy become a reality)?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74587/discussion-on-question-by-hankca-if-humans-found-unlimited-energy-would-there-b).